# Django: Is remote database connect faster than Default database?

Tags: django, database, performance, postgresql

I had to load a million entries in my postgreSQL table from xls file and with default database settings it was taking more than 5 minutes (even after using raw SQL queries with cursor connect). So to improve the performance I tried it by remotely connecting (using psycopg2) the same database and it hardly took 100 seconds to insert all the entries.

```
mydb = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="test", password="test")
cursor = mydb.cursor() 
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TABLE')
```

Although I was able to find a faster solution, I was unable to find the reason behind why connecting to a database remotely is faster than connecting to the default database.

Comment: A guess - it could be that psycopg2 keeps the database connection open while django closes it after each query, try setting https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#conn-max-age param in your django db settings and see if it helps.